# Mute all laptop sounds, except from a Zoom meeting

Tags: cron, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, video

How can I mute all laptop sounds (including scripts that may be started by cron in future), except from a Zoom meeting? It will be good if I could save a set of those commands as a script and then execute it before meeting.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, Pulseaudio 13.0, Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.4.0-29-generic.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom uses H.323/SIP protocols to communicate, it has its own initiation rules via network through peers.Those kind of apps requires the mic/cam control before usage/meeting/call, if you can disable the cam/mic on computer that might work but i suggest to use official way because there might be problems when you try to re-enable (haven't tested) the mic/cam.

Zoom Mute Function (You must be host or have the permission given by host to perform that kind of features on zoom or related platforms):

https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/203435537-Mute-All-And-Unmute-All

If you want to disable the cam/mic on a Linux computer, this link might be helpful:

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/disable-webcam-microphone-linux/

Also if you want to change the volume for specific applications (GNOME Alsa Mixer):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/119574/is-there-a-volume-mixer